# Symfony2 app/console --env throws no envirorment name

Tags: symfony

I'm working with symfony2 and while migrating from Beta2 version to the current one I messed up with some environment configuration.

My trouble here is when I run

```
php app/console --env
```

I get the following error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
The file "MyWebRoute\symfony-standard\app/config/config_.yml" does not exist.
```

How should I get this working?
What should the proper configuration be?

Comment: Well have you tried verifying if the file config_.yml really does exist?

Comment: It doesn't. Should it exist? There is a config.yml file but no config_.yml one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is b/c you have to specify your environment.

Available by default are "prod" and "dev".

So if you want to have console do something regarding your development environment you do

```
./console --env=dev [...]
```

The error message stems from console trying to load the appropriate configuration file, which is config_dev.yml for "dev" and config_prod.yml for "prod" and config_.yml for ""; but that one doesn't exist.

Comment: For some reason. After running
    ./console --env=dev
I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: the SAME error? I don't thinks so and if so, then your download is broken and you should get the most recent release.

Comment: I've got the last one. I downloaded it yesterday. I get the same error when "./console --env".

Comment: There. --env needs always a parameter prod/dev/test etc...
Thought first needed to be specified a default and then it throws the actual environment. Mi mistake! Thanks!